# Android: Read GPS + Accelerometer Sensor Simultaneously

Tags: android, gps, accelerometer

I am attempting to make it so that I can read the GPS data which is triggered as an event every one minute, and as a result will also read the accelerometer data at the same time. However I am unable to do this I have attached what I have in my main file. Any help would be appreciated.

https://gist.github.com/4395787

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making request for GPS updates at 60000 milliseconds

Line 151

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 0,
            locationListener);
```

So make also accelerometer requests also at 60000 milliseconds (60000000 microseconds)

Line 71

```
sensorManager.registerListener(this,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            60000000 );
```

This will give you updates on almost same time if both your listeners start almost same time.